# Sublime text 3 proper indention for custom HTML element

Tags: html, ionic-framework, sublimetext3

I am using sublime text to do ionic project. It is common that we will have all those custom element like:

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The problem is sublime text doesn't seems to be work well with those custom element in indention. If I highlight all the code above and do reindent (`Edit → Line → Reindent`), the indention will become mess.

How can I get proper indention for this case? Any plugin to use?

Comment: Install the package controller plugin first this is the reference [linlk](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) and next install the ionic code snippet

Comment: @Anilkumar Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried with `ionic snippet` but it doesn't seems help at all.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify).

And then you can use by:

```
Ctrl+Shift+H (or Cmd+Shift+H if you're on a Mac).
```

-- or --

```
Right click in the current buffer and select HTML/CSS/JS Prettify -> Prettify Code.
```

However, for any JS, I'd use the [JSCS-Formatter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSCS-Formatter).